# How to parse JSON in non-strict mode in Spring REST to allow future new fields?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-rest

I have to expose a REST endpoint to receive notifications of Payment Transactions and the client API documentation has mentioned to "expect new fields to be added to the notification body in the future" and hence, I should parse it in a "non-strict format", so that if the parser sees new fields, it should not throw an exception. It should gracefully ignore the new fields.

How do I achieve this parsing of JSON in a non-strict format? Since my application heavily uses Spring, I have been using the standard Spring MVC Controller -

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> notify(@RequestBody PaymentNotification notification) {
    ...
}
```

where PaymentNotification is a POJO (with no annotations) that Spring will deserialize the JSON into on it's own. Since my POJO has static fields, will this make this parsing strict by default? How can I achieve non-strict parsing of JSON to Java object, preferably using Spring REST capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below annotation. Please import fasterxml jackson libraries if needed.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
public class PaymentNotification {
  // logic here
}
```

Comment: Switch the property to true and you got an answer :)

Comment: @MartinFrey I googled around it to find that your answer should be correct. Funny thing is, I have a framework which creates the POJO classes from beans I define in an xml file. There are no annotations in the generated POJO class and I don't think there is a provision to give them as well. However, my code did not break when I gave extra fields in the request. Does Spring magically handle this scenario or is there a configuration that governs this behaviour and is by default set to non-strict mode?